# Whereabouts would I find the source code for the CVS team integration in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, cvs

I've looked at a lot of the git repositories, but I'm not sure which one to start with (and they're fairly large, so I want to avoid scanning 25 gig of data). Where would I find the code to handle CVS and Subversion integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can browse all of the git repositories at http://git.eclipse.org/c/ . The one you want is http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.team.git/ (cloning URLs are shown at the bottom).

Answer (score 1):

You can install the core Eclipse source including the CVS code in to Eclipse from `Help > Install New Software`. Work with `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3` for Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler) and choose `Eclipse SDK`.  You can also download this as base Eclipse install (which is what I usually do).

Once you have this installed open `Preferences > Plug-in Development` and check `Include all plug-ins from target in Java search`. Once this is set the things like `Navigate > Open Type` and all the Java searches will include all the Eclipse source code.

Where the SVN code is depends on which SVN code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Update 2022: as illustrated by [gitlab.eclipse.org/eclipsefdn/helpdesk issue 1100](https://gitlab.eclipse.org/eclipsefdn/helpdesk/-/issues/1100), and [issue 915](https://gitlab.eclipse.org/eclipsefdn/helpdesk/-/issues/915), everything is in the process to be transferred to GitHub.

The old (2014-2021) [`git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.team.git/`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.team.git/) would therefore be soon (Q2 2022) be found under https://github.com/eclipse-platform.

https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.team